# Performance of Postgresql Merge vs Insert & Update statements

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I would like to know will my performance of my SP's written in postgresql is going to improve if I move my insert and update statement to the merge statement or it will hamper the performance.

Also if you can provide any official/trustworthy link on the same would be really appreciable.

Just FYI, I am using Postgresql in AWS Aurora Serverless.

Thanks

Comment: How are getting MERGE? The MERGE command has only existed in PostgreSQL for one week, and is not yet included in any production-ready release.

Comment: If you mean the SQL standard `Merge` statement, you cannot as Postgres does not support it. If you mean the PostgreSQL extension `on conflict` then yes when an existing unique value already exists then if will hamper performance (generally by some .1 ms) - it is doing twice as much work.  But the alternative it that it throws an exception.  Official/trustworthy link sure: The [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) also any **AWS supplied documentation**.

Comment: @jjanes Do you mean that MERGE statement cannot be used in PostgreSQL as of now? Also i found the following link on the same. Can you please confirm what it is?      https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/23520/sql-merge.html

Comment: @Belayer I am talking about MERGE statement which will do function of both insert or update in PostgreSQL as i am asked that doing this will improve the performance of the code. Currently i am using update and insert statement in my SP's. Can you confirm whether is it possible to use MERGE in PostgreSQL or not? I also found this link. can you confirm what this is saying? https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/23520/sql-merge.html

Comment: That is the SQL Standard Merge (used in Oracle, MS SQL Serve, DB2, others?). It has been proposed in Postgres for quite some time. But as of v14.2 Postgres does not support it. It appears v15 will, at least it is in the [devl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/sql-merge.html) documentation at this point, but it still could be removed.  Will it improve performance? I would guess that is highly doubtful. But until well tested under a full range of conditions cannot be confirmed either way.